# MATLAB Combining Arrays Based on Certain Columns that Match

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file with the variables day(in julian) lat, lon, and ozone. I have converted that file into a 3D matrix of lon, lat, and day (in that order).

I also have a .mat file with Year, Month, Day (in regular 1, 2, 3 format), Lat, Long in a 2D table.

I need to put the value of the ozone from the NetCDF file into the .mat file as an additional column while matching the day, lat, and lon between the two files. So basically, I have to find which ozone values correspond to the day, lat, and lon of the .mat file and add that value in as a separate column. Not all ozone values will be used.

What kind of script would be able to do this? I'm very new to MATLAB and this is very difficult for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: just to clarify: dataset 1 contains a date, two coordinates and an ozone level; dataset 2 contains a date and two coordinates - the task is to use dataset 2 as a filter for dataset 1?

Comment: dataset 1 is a 3D matrix in which x is the lon, y is the lat, and z is the day (julian day).

dataset 2 contains several columns: year, month, day, julian day, lat, lon.

Combine the two datasets so that where the julian day, lat, and lon match for both will form a new array with julian day, lat, lon, and ozone.

It would be nice to write a loop in which, if the julian day, lat, and lon match between dataset 1 and 2, it is placed in a matrix with julian day, lat, lon, and ozone info. If not, it is placed in a separate matrix with the same info.

Hope that's clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options you can look at:

```
A{1,1} = {'Monday 7/15';...
          'Tuesday 8/01'; ...
          'Wednesday 1/21';...
          'Thursday 2/30';...
          'Friday 11/02'};

A{2,1} = [0.1234; ...
          0.2345; ...
          0.3465; ...
          0.4576; ...
          0.5687];

B = {'Wednesday 1/21'; ...
     'Friday 11/02'};

k = 1;
for i = 1:size(A{1,1},1)
    for j = 1:size(B,1)
        if strcmp(A{1,1}(i),B(j)) == 1
            OZONE(k) = A{2,1}(i);
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

or, probably more suitable for the Julian date format:

```
A{1,1} = [1234.5; ...
          2345.6; ...
          3456.7; ...
          4576.8; ...
          5678.9];

A{2,1} = [0.1234; ...
          0.2345; ...
          0.3465; ...
          0.4576; ...
          0.5687];

B = [2345.6; ...
     5678.9];

k = 1;
for i = 1:size(A{1,1},1)
    for j = 1:size(B,1)
        if A{1,1}(i) == B(j)
            OZONE(k) = A{2,1}(i);
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

One of the two loop examples above should allow you to check your dataset for the dates you need.